# Is it possible to pass in variables through an aws autoscaling group to an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, autoscaling

I am trying to spin up 2 ec2 instances, that are essentially the exact same server, except that they are differentiated by name (ie. server-01 and server-02).  I'm using an autoscaling group to make sure that if an instance crashes, that a new one spins up automatically.  Also, the launch script that is passed to each instance includes their hostname (server-01 etc.) that is needed for a configuration file.  It would be a lot cleaner to just have one asg with 2 concurrent instances that passes this variable into the individual instances, but then there is the issue of first, is it even possible to pass in a variable into an asg launch script, and then if one instance goes down, wouldn't the variable then go to server-03 for example?

To me, it seems that I need to create 2 asgs each with a single instance, but I was wondering of the above is possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

If your two Amazon EC2 instances are performing different functions then, yes, it would be correct to use two different Auto Scaling groups.

When multiple instances are launched under one Auto Scaling group, it is expected that each instance is performing an identical function. There should certainly be no need to give each instance a specific reference number (eg 1, 2) and have a replacement instance assume that number.

The alternative is to have each instance inspect the environment at startup. It could `DescribeInstances()` with a tag of the Auto Scaling group to discover currently-running instances in the group. Then, you could use `Name` tags to track what each instance is doing. For example, if it sees that there is only `Server-2` running, then it should assume that it needs to take the place of `Server-1`.

Much better to either use separate Auto Scaling groups or make each instance identical.